# Force php to use proxy

Tags: php, proxy

I have to tell my php to use proxt settings to allow a connection with website. So how can I force php script to use proxy?

I scraped some HTTP proxy and I want to use them.

I tried adding this to `config.php`

```
stream_context_set_default(['http'=>['proxy'=>'101.66.253.22:8080
']]);
```

I also tried to change function from this:

```
$ch = curl_init(Site::LINK_LOGIN);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

to this:

```
$ch = curl_init(Site::LINK_LOGIN);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '101.66.253.22:8080');      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

But none of wchich works properly. Can you help me?

Comment: `stream_context_set_default` is used for functions like `fopen` or `file_get_contents`, not the cURL library so it wouldn't have any impact on your cURL calls.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a new curl_setopt with proxy port.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://proxy.example.com"); //proxy url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, "8080"); // proxy port number
```

Maybe...
But first check the error message

```
if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}
```

Comment: Splitting ip and port does not solve my problem.

After adding your functions i got: "Operation completed without any errorsCurl error: couldn't connect to hostOperation completed without any errorsOperation completed without any errorsOperation completed without any errors"

Comment: It looks like you're making 5 cURL calls there and one of them is failing. You might want to trace which of those calls failed.